# PHPWord returns blank document [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpword

I am trying to insert some data to the template however I keep getting a blank document with no data or template structure. It is just blank.

Here is the code:

```
    $path = public_path('documents/mailing/');

    $source = public_path('documents/default/main.docx');

    $sales = Sale::where('status', '=', '1')
        ->where('special', '!=', 1)
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')
        ->get();

    if( !File::exists($path) )
    {
        File::makeDirectory($path, 0775, true);
    }

        $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

        $template = $phpWord->loadTemplate($source);

        foreach ($sales as $sale)
        {
            $template->addPage();
            $template->setValue('saleRef', htmlspecialchars($sale->SaleID));

        }


        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        $file = $path.'mailing_'.date("d-m-Y_H-i-s"). '.docx';
        $objWriter->save($file);
```

I have also tried saving the template like so:

```
        $file = $path.'mailing_'.date("d-m-Y_H-i-s"). '.docx';
        $template->saveAs($file);
```

But when I do that I am getting a corrupted document in return with some XML errors which cannot be open in MS Word. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @SariYono Here: https://postimg.org/image/y4a5a1xb3/

Comment: does it do the same thing if you add a section vs a page?

Comment: @SariYono How I could implement that with ->loadtemplate ?. When i replace ->addPage with ->addSection it gives me Call to undefined method.